# TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'unicode' python concatenation

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, if-statement

I am trying to use a print statement to print out certain elements. I keep facing a TypeError when doing so.  The error shows :

```
File "data.py", line 58, in main
print ("Current file_size" , + data_current['File Name'], "does not match previous file_size" , + data_previous['File Name'])
```

TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'unicode'
My code is as follows :

```
if data_current['File Name'] == data_previous['File Name']:  # If file names match

   if data_current['File Size'] != data_previous['File Size']: # If file sizes do not match
                data_current = json.loads(cd)
                data_previous = json.loads(pd)
                print ("Current file_size" , + data_current['File Name'], "does not match previous file_size" , + data_previous['File Name'])
```

Comment: Its the unary operator. If i was to use x = + 2 that would be valid but in my case it is being interpreted as a full assignment statement.

Comment: You should use _either_ comma _or_ plus to concatenate your strings. I would recommend comma.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different formatting for your print statements.

Something like

```
print ("Current file_size {} does not match previous file_size {}".format(data_current['File Name'],data_previous['File Name'])
```

Otherwise try explicitly converting your variables to strings? i.e str(variable_name) before printing the value.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it this way. Thanks @Anton